Why IEnamerable.ForEach statement seems invalid?
I wrote foreach loop with an IEnamerable object.
void PromptAsmName_(System.Reflection.Assembly asm) => logger.Prompt($"Asm: {asm.FullName})");

var domain = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
domain.GetAssemblies()
     .ForEach((asm) => PromptAsmName_(asm));

logger.Prompt($"Count of Asm({domain.FriendlyName}): {domain.GetAssemblies().Count()}");

but no name was shown.  although the count of the names appeared normally.
Count of Asm(DefaultDomain): 209

Why?
I thought it had something to do with the laziness of GetAssemblies() but I'm not sure.
update:
the Foreach method is not in standard library. it's in the ChoETL library. here is the definition:
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            action(item);
            yield return item;
        }
    }

Thank you @Etienne de Martel for pointing this out in comment.

What is ForEach? That's not in .NET (there's one on List<T>, but GetAssemblies() returns an array). Where does it come from? How is it defined?

Thank you for your remark. I misunderstood. ForEach is defined in ChoETL library.
I'll update my question.

The yield return makes it lazy. You're going to have to enumerate it somehow. But by then why not use a regular foreach statement? Personally, I don't think it's good design, since in practice it's basically a Select with extra steps. Also, in general, LINQ methods are supposed to be pure, and a ForEach can only function with side effects.

It's easy to write one liner. but certainly you're right. It is a bad design.

I realized it's not a list but an iterator. I needed to iterate it explicitly.
like (IEnumerable).ForEach(...).ToList();
It's not pure(sideeffective), and extra notation would be required. (for the iterating action : ToList, ToArray ... etc.)

The problem is not that you feed that ForEach an IEnumerable, but that it returns one

yes. it's the use of yield return and returning an iterator that's causing it. Thanks for pointing that out. I have a better understanding now.
